# Twitter "Tweet" button not working

Tags: html, twitter

This one has had me stumped for a while.
I have the following code in **CodePen**:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button color-change"
  href="https://twitter.com/share" target="_blank"
  data-size="large"
  data-text="Never doubt that a small group of thoughtful, committed citizens can change the world; indeed, it's the only thing that ever has. - Margaret Mead"
  data-hashtags="RuairiMcN">
<i id="twitter" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

It's a Twitter share button, it should open a Twitter page where you can make a tweet with the content of "data-text". However, if you follow it, the Tweet box is populated with something different:
"https://s.codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-b5c36245-7638-5a23-0a1b-4b5fab51692a/index.html"

No idea where that's coming from. Re-read the parameters for this button from the Twitter Dev area with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't loaded the Twitter widget Javascript properly. (This is step 4 in "[How to add a Tweet button to your website](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button#how-to-add-a-tweet-button-to-your-website)".) Without that Javascript loaded, the only information that Twitter has is the referrer -- in this case, that's something internal to Codepen.